# Unable to catch adLDAP Exception on Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, exception, adldap

When I get an exception while running the below code, it does not return the exception message but loads Laravel’s error handling page. I’m trying to return the exception error message.

```php
            try {
                $adldap = new adLDAP(Config::get('app.ldap'));
            }
            catch (adLDAPException $e) {
                return $e; 
            }
```

[image: Laravel handling the exception]

Comment: According to the error you're receiving you should be catching an `\adLDAP\adLDAPException` (notice the full namespace there).

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue and discovered that AdLDAP 5.0.0 onwards requires you to use 'adLDAP\Exceptions\adLDAPException'.

Rob Ganly